# get 'undefined' saveResult.entities after saveChanges [breezejs]

Tags: breeze

I tried to update one entity in my angularjs client using breezejs library. After calling saveChanges(), it can actually save back in the server and fetched on the client. However, the server did not return the response back. The saveResult.entities is undefined and pop up an error for me. When I took a look at the docs, it mentions 'Some service APIs do not return information about every saved entity. If your server doesn't return such information, you should add the pre-save, cached entity to saveResult.entities yourself'. Could anyone provide an example of how to do this?

This is the code when i am trying to do an update.

```
manager.saveChanges(entitiesToSave, null, (saveResult) => {
   const savedRes = saveResult;
   savedRes.entities = entitiesToSave;
   return savedRes;
}).then(saveSucceeded);
```

Comment: What is your server-side technology stack?

Comment: Olingo Odata V2. After the update, this is the response coming back.

--changeset_163c0553-73a6-436d-afa7-cbd8a8e3a3fd
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Id: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0


--changeset_163c0553-73a6-436d-afa7-cbd8a8e3a3fd--

Comment: Is there any way to change from client side?

Answer (score 0):

On the server, you would need to construct the response for an `update` similar to the way it is for a `create`:

```
response.setContent(...); // entities
response.setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK.getStatusCode());
response.setHeader(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, responseFormat.toContentTypeString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i cannot change the response from server side as I am using Olingo ODATA. Is there any way we can do to change breeze side?